# Website mobile version and media query version are different

Tags: html, css, sass

I thought that I could use media queries for both mobile version and desktop version with low width, but

1. objects with `position: fixed` property behave differently, and fixing it for the mobile version messes up the desktop version.
2. `overflow-x: hidden` doesn't work for the mobile version. Yes, I have a `<meta name="viewport">` tag and yes, I wrapped everything in a div inside body, and gave it the `overflow-x: hidden` property, but it doesn't seem to work. Even `position: relative` or `position: fixed`, don't do the trick.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: Edit your question by adding your code so we can help you better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .myDiv {
        position: initial !important;
    }
}
```

The !important css tag will ensure that the css is taken into account.